# Which of the following equations determines a vector subspace of $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Which of the following equations determines a vector subspace of $\mathbb R^3$

$A) z = x^2 + y^2$

$B) z^2 = x^2 + y^2$

$C) -z^2 = x^2 + y^2$

$D) x+y+z= 1$

$E) \text { None of the above}$

I'm not quite sure how to think about it. If I have specific vectors then I can see geometrically that they go through the origin but here if say $(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)$, I would think they all go through the origin and create subspaces but I don't really understand what is meant I suppose.

Comment: If you have no intuition, try to prove that they are vector spaces. Hopefully, in those which aren't vector spaces, you'll encounter roadblocks which will allow you envision the truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a) we wish to determine if $V=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3:z=x^2+y^2\}$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$. But note that $\vec v=(-1,0,1)$ and $\vec w=(1,0,1)$ are in $V$ while
$$
\vec v+\vec w=(0,0,2)\notin V
$$
This proves that $V$ is not a subspace.

Can you carry this idea over to your other potential subspaces?

Comment: so for B, we could use those same vectors as in A to show that V is not a subspace. For C, I don't think anything besides (0,0,0) will work because squares are positive. For D, if we take (1,0,0) and (0,1,0) then (1,0,0) + (0,1,0) = (1,1,0) and this is also not an element of V so I say E) None of the above?

Comment: @StephanCasey that's mostly correct. For (c) only $(0,0,0)$ works. Is $\{(0,0,0)\}$ a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: Oh yes it is thanks