# Which of the following are vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Which of the following are vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

1. $W = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}\, \middle|\, x \ge 0\right\}$
2. $W = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}\, \middle|\, x \ge 0, y \ge 0\right\}$
3. $W = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}\, \middle|\, x = 0\right\}$

I know that $W$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$ if $W$ is a vector space under the operations of addition and scalar multiplication defined in $V$. So what do I do? In each example shall I choose two matrices for example in each one that are in $W$ and check if their sum is in $\mathbb{R}^2$? And take a particular scalar and prove that scalar multiplication is also in $\mathbb{R}^2$? But what exactly is $\mathbb{R}^2$? I read in the book that is the set of all ordered pairs. How exactly does that work with matrices?

Explain each one please!
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Seems like you are a new user . Please show your work . What do you know about subspaces ?.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of posting the question in the post itself, since linked questions are frowned upon here, but really you should be doing the work of typing out these questions yourself. Questions which give the impression that you want everyone to do your work for you tend to be downvoted, especially if they appear to be homework questions.

Comment: To counteract such impressions, you should mention what sort of things you have tried, or at least give evidence of *some* sort of personal investment in trying to find the answer to your question.

Comment: Yes. I'm new born in here. Don't really know how things work here.

I know that W is a subspace of a vector space V if W is a vector space under the operations of addition and scalar multiplication defined in V.

So what do I do?

in each matrix shall choose two matrices for example in each one that are in W and give them value to the variables that meet the requirement and check if the addition is in R^2? and take a particular scalar a prove that scalar multiplicacion is also in R^2?

But what exactly is R^2? I read in the book that is the set of all ordered pairs.

Comment: didn't post the question itself because I'm not used to the math programming for this... if there any easy way to post here the math stuff will appreciate any recommendation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which of the following equations determines a vector subspace of $\mathbb R^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1181292/which-of-the-following-equations-determines-a-vector-subspace-of-mathbb-r3)

Comment: This site uses MathJax for formatting mathematical formulae. Here's a reference on how to use it:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Try to put some of that info you mentioned into the question and perhaps it will ameliorate some of the downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

The first two are not vector subspaces. Consider the vector $(1,1)$. It is contained in each of the two sets, but its additive inverse is not, so neither set is a subspace. The third set is a subspace. Given two vectors in $W$, they are of the form $(0,y_1)$, $(0,y_2)$ and their sum is $(0,y_1 + y_2)$ which is again in $W$, and given any scalar $r$ it follows that $r(0,y_1) = (0,ry_1)$ is again in $W$. Therefore $W$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, so it is a vector subspace.

Comment: can I choose values for y in a) and c) even I don't have information of y?

Comment: Yes, there are no restrictions on what values $y$ can be, so we are free to make them whatever we like.

Comment: ok.. and those are in W.. how do I show they are in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: btw thanks for the help and the advices...

Comment: $W$ by definition is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. You seem to be confused by the fact that elements in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are being treated both as ordered pairs and as column vectors. As you read in your book, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is defined to be the set of ordered pairs of elements of $\mathbb{R}$. But for some purposes, it can be convenient to express elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as column vectors, with the first component at the top and the second component at the bottom. You should regard this as merely a change in notation, they are essentially the same thing...

Comment: oh ok!!! I understand now...
could you please give me a counterexample to understand why the first two aren't vector spaces? Ok or.. check if my reasoning is right.

in the first one... 
if I take the column vector of (1,1) which is in W and another column vector in W, let's say (2,2).. is closed under sum because (3,3) is in W but no is closed under scalar multiplication because if I multipy by -1 the first for example -1 (1,1) I get (-1,-1) which is not in W because the x must be 0 or positive. right? something like this would apply to the second one... right?